# Ghost touch Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: screen

I have a strange problem with my desktop today. I'm so sorry if this was already asked before. I notice that it's the first time I encounter this issue. I didn't touch any button of my mouse but the screen is moving up and down and won't let me read some web pages. I've made an youtube [video](https://youtu.be/LYS6gIhU3s8) with my smartphone to show what happens exactly. I hope the link is working. I tried all the internet browser I own in my distro (i.e. Firefox, chromium or Chrome) but they have the same problem.

My comp specs : 
Pentium 4 2.8Ghz - 2GB of RAM - GPU : AGP AMD graphic Card with 1GB of memory. Single boot with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried removing your mouse and seeing if that changes it, if so then your mouse probably got messed up. If not let me know so I can think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is that your mouse is broken. Try unplugging your mouse, and see if the problem goes away. If it does, then it's an issue with the mouse itself, not with Ubuntu. The most likely problem is that there's some dirt or something similar in the mouse, which is confusing the sensors.

If it *is* the mouse itself, you could either get a new one, or take it apart with a screwdriver, and see if there's any dirt or oter object in there which you can remove.